# AWS WordPress Admin: Plugin installation and updating settings causes the page to hang forever

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I'm working on a WP installation set up on an AWS instance. Whenever I try to install a plugin or change ANY setting, I press the button to apply the changes, and the page simply loads forever without redirecting. If I refresh after awhile, I can see that the action was applied as expected.

Same thing applies to submitting new posts - Chrome will take me to an error page saying the "page isn't working", but if I refresh, the post submitted just fine. Literally anything that requires submitting a form, this issue applies to.

How can I begin to debug this? I have no idea what's going on. I've set up Wordpress countless times but never on AWS.

Comment: What initial image are you using for the WP install?  I'm going to guess there is a permission issue somewhere - I did a WP install on AWS and it required a hella more configuration than I'm used to.

Comment: The installation was setup by my boss. It's Wordpress powered by Bitnami, which I assume is automatically setup using the AWS management console.

Comment: I have SSH access, so I should be able to set permissions there (doesn't work through filezilla). Any specific directories I should check?

Comment: yea, I have to pass this on to more expert folks.  yes, you'll need SSH and you'll learn some command line during this project...  I'm not sure if you can edit your question to include AWS in the title to help find someone with the right skills...

Comment: This may be related to FastCGI - could you try to edit wp-`includes/pluggable.php` and comment out lines 1171-1172 (those about the `status_header` call in `wp_redirect`) and see if it help? Will provide a proper fix if it does.

Comment: @vard Just tried that, no luck unfortunately.